# Sense coil based leakage current meter (with LCD display)

Tags: protection

This is the circuit diagram of the previous Leviton GFCI receptable without auto-monitoring self test.

[image: 1]

Do you (or others) know whether the current coming out of the sense transformer or sense coil is directly the differential current of say 3mA? Or does it come out much lesser than that (for example 3 uA) and the chipset has to amplify it to become 3mA?

Because if the leakage current existing the sense coil is actual.. then one can simply put an ammeter before the chipset and lcd display to output the actual leakage current.

Original message:

I'm looking for a meter that can not only detect but also DISPLAY leakage current (in an LCD display) that is based on the sense coil technology in GFCI. So imagine a plug-in meter where you can plug to existing outlet or extension cord then your appliance plugged to the device and can show (by means of DISPLAY) whether it's leaking 1mA to 50mA leakage current.

Anyone has encountered such device? I want to study how different appliance leaks to study nuisance leaking in GFCI application.